# Raspbian compile single kernel module gfs2

Tags: mount, kernel, compile, raspbian, kernel-module

I'm trying my best to get GFS2 mounted in dual-primary on Raspbian, but I'm hitting an issue. Whenever I try to mount the GFS2 volume, I get an error:

```
mount -t gfs2 -o noatime,nodiratime,noquota /dev/drbd0 /data
mount: mount(2) failed: /data: No such file or directory
```

I've read up about this and there seems scant information about this. I have determined that the linux kernel config file `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.14.79+/.config` shows this as an unconfigured part of the kernel module:

```
CONFIG_GFS2_FS=m
# CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM is not set
```

I think this means it needs to be enabled to `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM=y` and recompiled.

I am running into a lot of issues with 1) determining the correct module and 2) getting it correctly compiled and installed.
I think it is part of `fs/gfs2` or `fs/dlm`.

After setting the `.config` file, I have been trying to compile them using the commands:

```
make modules SUBDIRS=fs/dlm
make modules_install SUBDIRS=fs/dlm
make modules SUBDIRS=fs/gfs2
make modules_install SUBDIRS=fs/gfs2
```

Then:

```
modprobe dlm
modprobe gfs2
```

Still I get the same errors when trying to mount the filesystem.

I'm stuck, can anyone help?